# What's a word used when you don's see flaws on a person, even when they are there?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember a word, which definition I found on a movie if I remember correctly. The idea is to see someone as almost free of defects, even if those defects are there. It is what happens when someone is in love, thinking that everything the other person do is great. It is similar to bedazzled, but a false sense of it. I've been looking all over the internet and I just can't find it.

Thank you.

Comment: besotted.........

Comment: rose-colored glasses

Comment: Perhaps idealized?

Comment: I feel like Idealized fits the description. Still, I'm sure it was something else, or maybe I'm just tricking myself.  Thank you!